# AutoCorrect in WPF Richtextbox

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, .net-4.6.1

I read on [MSDN](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wpf/archive/2015/10/26/wpf-in-net-4-6-1.aspx) that .NET 4.6.1 supports auto correct now. 
The files in %appdata%/Microsoft/Spelling// were created automatically and I added the following line to the default.acl (file is still UTF-16 with BOM):

```
tramampoline|trampoline
```

I have set the project to target 4.6.1 and enabled SpellCheck on a RichTextBox:

```
<RichTextBox SpellCheck.IsEnabled="True" Language="de-DE"/>
```

While it highlights the word when typed wrong in the usual manner, there is no autocorrection happening.

What am I missing here?
I don't quite understand the note:

> Note: These new file-formats are not directly supported by the WPF spell checking API’s, and the custom dictionaries supplied to WPF in applications should continue to use .lex files.

Comment: When I add "trambampolin" to the default.dic file, The Richtextbox no longer marks the word as misspelled.

Comment: When rightclicking "trambampolin" I also get the string from the .acl file suggested as replacement. But I would like to have it replaced automatically (like autocorrect usually works) when hitting (e.g.) space.

Comment: The reference to .acl files in the MSDN article exists for the sake of completeness towards describing the ISpellChecker dictionary registration under %appdata%. I think this reference is somewhat misleading - WPF has not introduced auto correction. Rather, WPF uses this underlying dictionary registration mechanism to the extent that the dictionaries are relevant for its capabilities, namely error detection and offering suggestions. The MSDN article probably needs to clarify this point clearly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this is old, but as far as I know you need to handle AutoCorrect on your own (if I'm wrong please correct me with an example). You can do this as follows:

```
var caretPosition = richTextBox.CaretPosition;
// Make sure you're passing a textpointer at the end of the word you want to correct, i.e. not like this ;)
errorPosition = richTextBox.GetNextSpellingErrorPosition(caretPosition, LogicalDirection.Backward);
if(errorPosition == null)
{
    return;
}

var errors = richTextBox.GetSpellingError(errorPosition);
// Default would be to only replace the text if there is one available replacement
// but you can also measure which one is most likely with a simple string comparison
// algorithm, e.g. Levenshtein distance
if (errors.Suggestions.Count() == 1) 
{
    var incorrectTextRange = richTextBox.GetSpellingErrorRange(errorPosition);
    var correctText = error.Suggestions.First();
    var incorrectText = incorrectTextRange.Text;

    // Correct the text with the chosen word...
    errors.Correct(correctText);
}

// Set caret position...
```

An important note would be not to use the RTB's CaretPosition, but rather to use a textpointer at the end of the word you wish to correct. If your textpointer/caret is in a weird spot (e.g. the end of 20 whitespaces), the GetNextSpellingErrorPosition method may take up to 60 seconds before it returns (depending on the hardware/number of words in your RTB).